# inserting javascript file to the dom (approach comparison)

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a website widget that requires a javascript file, which renders a widget and I'm wondering what is the difference between 2 different approaches:

1. including JS file normally: (typekit uses this one)

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/mty1vkg.js"></script>
   ```
2. inserting the JS file dynamically to the DOM (google analytics example)

   ```
   (function() {
       var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
       ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'http://' : 'http://') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
       var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
     })();
   ```

Whats the difference between those approaches and what are the advantages? Which approach should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach is used when you want to have the widget loaded in the beginning. I.e. if that's something important for you then you could add the js file in a <script> tag. I'm sure you are using *.ready* event or something like that to be sure that everything is loaded. So, in point one you have:

1. Loading the page's assets
2. Loading the widget file
3. The *onload* event is fired
4. Your application logic starts
5. Initialize the widget

The second approach is suitable for things which are not directly affecting the page, or they are with lower priority. The flow is:

1. Loading the page's assets
2. The *onload* event is fired
3. Your application logic starts
4. Loading the widget file
5. Initialize the widget

I think it depends of how important is your widget. In some cases the second option is better, because you are showing something to the user as soon as possible and then load the fancy things. If you follow this way your widget will not affect the initial page rendering.

Answer (score 1):

The second approach loads the javascript asynchronously which means that the page doesn't need to wait for it while it is loading the rest of the content.

This approach is obviously advantageous where you have large js libraries to add to your page but it does mean that the library is not necessarily available unless your code is triggered from a callback within it.

If you load the js normally using a script tag, just inside the closing body tag of the page this is normally perfectly sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

There are many considerations.

Google Analytics is a script that should run last, because it has very low priority. They advise you to place it just before `</body>`. This ensures that their script is run *last*. Then they lazy-load the actual analytics-script to reduce initial page load time. So: run last and run lazy.

If you include the full script in the header your code will be parsed before the DOM is rendered. This delays rendering of the DOM by just a little bit.

In practice though these performance tweaks are only useful to consider if you're dealing with large volume or otherwise performance constrained devices, like mobile. I've you've got a lot of widgets and a lot of Javascript code, of which *most* will get run right away, I wouldn't bother too much with lazy loading. Only when you see a clear performance benefit, go for the fancy tricks.

You'll gain more performance by compiling/minifying your JavaScript, enabling (gzip) compression and setting up proper cache headers (fingerprinting et al.). There is never not a reason to do these.